# Passing data types to C++ class contructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, constructor

I extremely need to pass data types to the constructor of classes. I’m working on image processing (till now in Matlab) and now need to use ITK and VTK libraries. In fact, my images are coming from different types and sizes. Unfortunately, I don’t know how to pass a data type to my classes. It’s really painful to have different copies of same classes with different data types!!! 
Here is a very simple example to express what I mean and need. In this example, I’m going to create a dynamic array of “int” type. This exaple works well but I don't know how to employ templates. Could you please let me know how I can change the code to be able define any type of dynamic array?
Thanks in advance,

**Main**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Myclass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
Myclass c1;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Class definition:

**Myclass.h**

```
class Myclass
{
public:
Myclass();
~Myclass();


private:
int size;
int* my_dynamic_array;
void SetPrivate();
};
```

**Myclass.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Myclass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
Myclass::Myclass()
{
cout << "Please enter the size of array: ";
cin >> size;

my_dynamic_array = new int[size];
SetPrivate();
}



void Myclass::SetPrivate() {
cout << "\n\nPlease enter " << size << " numbers for the array elements...";
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << "\n\n#" <<i+1<<" : ";
    cin >> my_dynamic_array[i];

}
}


Myclass::~Myclass()
{
delete[] my_dynamic_array;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a raw pointer instead of a `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: Please have a look at the [template declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) reference, especially the [class template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) and [function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) links.

Comment: Are you looking for templates?

Comment: I dont use vectors because of the fact that I need to work with images in 2D and 3D spaces...

Comment: You can still use `std::vector` for that.

Comment: I googled a lot and similar questions were raised and the proposed solutions were based on templates. I know how to use templates for simple functions but for a constructor or a class it becomes complicated to me!!!

Comment: Why don't you create base image class, then create derived classes with whatever types and sizes you need. Then pass base class pointer to constructor.

Comment: victor, could you please explain more about it by an example...

Comment: Will you need to implement different algorithms depending on image types? If you need the run same exact operations, then template as said above is the best choice, if you work with them differently, then create derived classes.

Comment: yes, I'm going to use the same operations and, subsequently, templates, but I don't know how to pass datatypes in such an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not commenting on whether you could use `vector` instead of `int *my_dynamic_array`, I just translated your code into a template. Hope it helps somehow:

```
template<typename T>
class ImageClass {
public:
    ImageClass<T>() {
        cout << "Please enter the size of array: ";
        cin >> this->size;

        my_dynamic_array = new T[this->size];
        SetPrivate();
    }

    void SetPrivate() {
        cout << "\n\nPlease enter " << this->size << " numbers for the array elements...";
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++) {
            cout << "\n\n#" <<i+1<<" : ";
            cin >> my_dynamic_array[i];

        }
    }
protected:
    int size;
    T *my_dynamic_array;

};

int main() {

    ImageClass<int> ic_i;
    ImageClass<double> ic_d;
}
```

Comment: Constructor doesn't need `<T>`, in fact I am not even sure if it is legal there